# Printing Alpha image

Tags: printing, mfc, gdi+

I'm new to printer

How to print alpha image?

I'm using Gdi+'s DrawImage to draw image.

[image: Image with Alpha]

(Light-gray part is Black Color with 20% alpha)

But, Results it not as I expected.

It seems like discard alpha.

[image: Image Printed]

I'm using following code to print

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <gdiplus.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "gdiplus.lib")
using namespace Gdiplus;

INT main()
{
   // Initialize GDI+.
   GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;
   ULONG_PTR gdiplusToken;
   GdiplusStartup(&gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, NULL);

   // Get a device context for the printer.
   HDC hdcPrint = CreateDC(NULL, TEXT("\\\\printserver\\HP CP3505_2F"), NULL, NULL);

   DOCINFO docInfo;
   ZeroMemory(&docInfo, sizeof(docInfo));
   docInfo.cbSize = sizeof(docInfo);
   docInfo.lpszDocName = L"GdiplusPrint";

   Bitmap image(L"e:\\__.png");
   StartDoc(hdcPrint, &docInfo);
   StartPage(hdcPrint);
      Graphics* graphics = new Graphics(hdcPrint);
      Pen* pen = new Pen(Color(255, 0, 0, 0));

      graphics->DrawImage(&image, 50, 50);

      delete pen;
      delete graphics;
   EndPage(hdcPrint);
   EndDoc(hdcPrint);

   DeleteDC(hdcPrint);
   GdiplusShutdown(gdiplusToken);
   return 0;
}
```

But, Using Word(MS-Office) image is printed as expected.

Please help.

---

Edit:

GDI Alphablend function draws image alpha part as a gray color.

It looks fine.

But, Overlapping alpha is not working correctly.

It simply just draw a gray alpha part twice.

Not an alpha blend.

[source](https://gist.github.com/newpolaris/120e6ef927750d8e4b65)

Comment: I think the ability to utilize alpha is dependent on the driver, and I wouldn't expect a printer driver to support it. Perhaps Word is rendering the entire image to a single bitmap without alpha, then printing that.

Comment: I don't think I have seen a printer that supports alpha.